# FFmpeg's -bt (Bitrate Tolerance) options...?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I want to encode video for Tablets and Mobile Phones by FFmpeg, is it important to set the '-bt' option??  If I just skip this option, does this affect the video playback on the devices??

> ‘-bt tolerance’ Set video bitrate tolerance (in bits, default 4000k).
>   Has a minimum value of: (target_bitrate/target_framerate). In 1-pass
>   mode, bitrate tolerance specifies how far ratecontrol is willing to
>   deviate from the target average bitrate value. This is not related to
>   min/max bitrate. Lowering tolerance too much has an adverse effect on
>   quality.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using libx264 to encode, then the answer is "no" because `-bt` has been removed as a libx264 option last time I checked. See [Remove bitrate tolerance from libx264 interface](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=2c5168afed8ddd798dae5909dba85ae3b611f894) for the commit details.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I am using the latest version of FFmpeg, but I still find the '-bt' option from the '-help' of FFmpeg. 

-bt                <int>   E.V.. set video bitrate tolerance (in bits/s)

Comment: Yes, the `-bt` option is still listed in `ffmpeg -h` because it can be used with other encoders. You did not mention your desired output format, so I assumed you were using libx264 as your encoder.